# API call for setting maximum webcam access for the users in one meeting for BigBluebutton

Tags: html5-video, bigbluebutton

I have installed Bigbluebutton ver 2.2 in UBUNTU 16.04 LTS as recommended in its [documentation](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/install.html). Also, I use the API call to make HTTPS requests to my Bigbluebutton server. However, I cannot find a proper way to limit the number of users who can share their webcams at the same time. There is a parameter in the configuration file for maxParticipants but not for the number of webcams. Also, there is a value in getMeetingInfo that you can access the number of webcams, however,  you cannot set this value. Any help or suggestion for a link, ideas, or API example is extremely welcomed.

Comment: based on what I have read till now and this link(https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues/1050) I think there's actually no way to accomplish that.